# fish shell, $PATH and symlinked binary

Tags: shell, path, symlink, fish

According to [these instructions](http://toolchain.gitbook.com/ebook.html) I linked a binary into `/usr/bin` as follows:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert /usr/bin
```

Now the symlink exists, and `/usr/bin` is obviously in `$PATH`:

```
   cls@clsmba > ls -lah /usr/bin/ebook-convert
    lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    64B Jul 18 13:00 /usr/bin/ebook-convert -> /Users/cls/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert
```

However, the fish shell doesn't know that it exists:

```
cls@clsmba > ebook-convert
fish: Unknown command 'ebook-convert'

cls@clsmba > ./usr/bin/ebook-convert
fish: Unknown command './usr/bin/ebook-convert'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From which directory, you are executing `./usr/bin/ebook-convert`?

Comment: from my home directory

Comment: You should try executing `/usr/bin/ebook-convert` without the leading `.`

Comment: That leads to the same error.

Comment: Does ~/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert have execute permissions?

Comment: Ah, I see what the error is. There is a mistake in the instructions - what is the `~` doing in front of `/Applications`? By copy-pasting this I created a symlink to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created `/usr/bin/ebook-convert` as a symlink. Then you attempted to run `./usr/bin/ebook-convert` (note the leading dot) which won't work unless your cwd is / (i.e., the root dir). Of course the main problem is you probably don't have a `/Users/cls/Applications` directory; or, if you do, it doesn't contain calibre.app. You probably want `/Applications` not `~/Applications`.